# Element Data-Binding in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, element

I have a template column in a DataGrid:

```
 <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" >

                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name,ElementName=rsAllSkills}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
 </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

And in the same xaml file, I have

```
<riaControls:DomainDataSource QueryName="GetSkillsQuery" AutoLoad="True" x:Name="rsAllSkills">
            <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
                <domain:XXXX context/>
            </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
</riaControls:DomainDataSource>
```

The DataSource has loaded everything successfully for sure, if I put that TextBlock out side of the DataGrid, it works; but inside the DataGrid, it doesn't load even the Name of rsAllSkills....

Could anybody give me a hint, thank you so much.

Comment: rsAllskills is not a name in the scope of the Template Column.  Scopes don't reach outside a `DataTemplate`.  You probably are going to need to include the DomainContext in the DataContext of the DataGrid somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Have a dummy converter and check the binding.

What I guess is, the DataTemplate inside the CellEditingTemplate would receive the parent's DataContext, ie., DataGrid's DataContext. So, to work around this you can do one thing.

1) Bind the `rsAllSkills` to the Tag Property of DataGridTemplateColumn. 
2) Now, Bind the TextBlock's Text property with the Tag property like,

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Tag="{Binding Name,ElementName=rsAllSkills}">
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" >    
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tag}"/>
              </StackPanel>         
         </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: I solved this problem by defining the Ria data source control as a static resource... but I will give your solution a shot and mark as solution if it works. Thanks!

Comment: @user299230 I guess, the static resource is the far best way. :)